# intergrate active directory login credentials using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, active-directory, intranet

I am learning active directory and want to setup a local intranet. I have a web app which requires authentication using windows login credentials. Is it possible to do the login function via javascript/jQuery? If so, how can I get the windows credentials.

I would appreciate any ideas..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Integrated Windows authentication works out of the box in Windows environment and can be setup at the web server (IIS) and typically does not require any additional coding. There are tons of resources out there about this topic.

Typically, you need to change Authentication of your web site in IIS from Anonymous to Windows and it should work. In some situations you might also need to adjust a browser settings - for example, if browser will prompt you for a login - it can be changed by configuring Integrated Windows authentication in IE - Internet Options - Advanced Tab.